# python installation path

Tags: python, path

I've tried making a package for my python project, and this has an sh script that does some post install python setup.py install for some dependencies/subprojects. But turns out that MacOS installer creates it's own context and screws up some paths so going simply:

```
  python setup.py install - won't work
```

One solution that seems to help is to do:

```
  usr/local/bin/python setup.py install
```

Now I'm kind of a newbie to MacOS so here are my questions:

1. Is this the default/standard location of python? What I mean is that I plan to distribute this package so can I expect that a machine that has python installed will have a usr/local/bin/python ?
2. In case that the answer to 1. is no, how could I get the location to their python installation? $PATH contains a lot more and $PYTHONPATH is not what I'm looking for either.

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: The MacOS installer will create it's own context while installing the project. So I can't really acces the real $PATH either. The $PATH during installation is /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec.

Comment: why do you need to access $PATH ?

Comment: I need access to python. But because the installer creates a different context I can't access it with "python setup.py install" for example because python is no longer part of the new context $PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly can **not** assume that python is installed there. If python is properly installed, it should be in the `$PATH`, otherewise you just can't know. I could have installed it at `/whatever/snake-program/`, if it wasn't in the path, how could you guess?

**EDIT:** What do you mean `$PATH` contains a lot more by the way? As long as there aren't more than one python install, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: What I mean is that $PATH contains more than just the path to python. Like my path: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Dev/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin:/Dev/flash_player_update_201002_flash10/Players:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin , I can't really use this to find the actual path to python.

Comment: Do you need to? If you can access `$PATH` in your script, you just need to call `python`. So I guess you can't access it?

Comment: The MacOS installer will create it's own context while installing the project. So I can't really acces the real $PATH either. The $PATH during installation is /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec.

Comment: Well, then I don't think there's much you can do acually - you'll have to ask the user about the proper location (of course, you could make a couple of educated guesses first, such as /usr/bin/python and /usr/local/bin/python and only ask if that fails). With a proper path you could call `which python` to find the location, so you could hint your users to call that (it relies on `$PATH` being set).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answers. Knew from the start PackageMaker will give me headaches :)